# Issue with using add_rewrite_rule() for post querying custom fields

Tags: query, post-meta, rewrite-rules

Here's what I'm trying to do. I made it so that the posts can store a postmeta value using a meta box textarea field.

Here's what I have done so far:

I extract the meta value and explode it to an array on line breaks, so I can access each value using the keys on the query by this function:

```
function custom_query_var( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'page_number';
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'custom_query_var' );
```

The query is working using this url structure:

```
http://domain.tld/post-slug/
http://domain.tld/post-slug/?page_number=1
http://domain.tld/post-slug/?page_number=2
http://domain.tld/post-slug/?page_number=3
...
```

They are all displaying the array value of the postmeta that I exploded in the post template. When there's no query, it just displays the post, as I intended.

---

Now, I'm thinking of accessing them by a url structure like this:

```
http://domain.tld/post-slug/   -> for the post itself (no custom query)
http://domain.tld/post-slug/1/ -> for the post with a custom query
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
function custom_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^(.*)/([0-9]+)',
        'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&page_number=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rules');
```

It doesn't seem to work, only displaying the post with no query happening. I'm not sure why, but I'm suspecting that I'm breaking a rule on **'posts'** using the said rewrite rule. Can anyone enlighten me about this issue?

Comment: pagename is the query for page post type, not posts. Also note that a rule already exists with that pattern, for paginated singular posts.

Comment: I wonder of I can override tha pagination of singular posts then. I tried using the add_rewrite_endpoint() function to the init to make a post url query like http://domain.tld/post-name/query/1/ and it's good, though I'd prefer overriding the post pagination if it can be done.